# Convert NSString to NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

i get a nsstring from a nsdictionary via:

```
inputString = [dataUsage valueForKey:@"amount"];
```

after that the string looks like: 23,56

how can i convert this string into a nsnumber?

i have tried the following:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:inputString];
[formatter release];
```

but this does not work. I think the problem is, that the "delimiter" is a comma. How can i fix this?

regards,
patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`-[NSNumberFormatter setLocale:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-CJBIGCCE)

You could also use `setDecimalSeparator:`, but `setLocale:` will take care of that as well.